# TypeError: service.getValue is not a function in Angular2 Unit-Testing a Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

> TypeError: service.getValue is not a function

```
let data: string;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
constructor() {
    myOtherObservableReturning.subscribe((data: mydata) => {
           data.items.forEach((item: Object)  => {
               .....
           }
        ...
        ...
    });
}
   public getValue() { return 'HelloWorld'; }
}
```

unit test:

```
let service: MyService;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: MyService, useValue: { data: Observable.of(dataStub) } }
        ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
});

it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(service)); 
    //LOG: '{"params":{"_isScalar":true,"scheduler":null}}'
});


it('should call getValue', () => {
    //TypeError: service.getValue is not a function
    expect(service.getValue()).toBe('HelloWorld');
});
```

I couldnt figure out why unit test cant find the function `getValue()`, I have already imported and checked its there in the service file.

Comment: what is `dataStub` in your `TestBed config`

Comment: @Paritosh `dataStub` is the mockData for `data: mydata` in MyService Constructor. I am trying to pump in fake mockData. Without this, compiler complains error too

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: The error you are facing because, in your `TestBed` `config` section, when you do `{ provide: MyService, useValue: { data: Observable.of(dataStub) } }`, the `MyService` instance you get (`service`), is your `fake mockData` - which might not be having `getValue` function.

Comment: That sounds true. But I thought I must give a fake `data: mydata` to the service so that it could resolve this error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`. How can I test the Service in a correct manner?

Comment: You are right. I removed `useValue: { data: Observable.of(dataStub) }` and it is now able to get the function I wanted in the test.

Comment: But it complains `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` on this line `data.items.forEach((item: Object)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given the the type of `service: MyService`. Typescript only assumes a variable to be of type `any` if type is not specified.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: MyService, useValue: { data: Observable.of(dataStub) } }
        ]
    });
    service: MyService = TestBed.get(MyService);
});
```

Comment: Yes. I have added `let service: MyService` but didn find the function as well

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: I need to initialize `data.items` to empty array. It was undefined, that is why error `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` pops.